# Pandas TimerGrouper: Index with beginning

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

My `pd.TimeGrouper("M")` groups daily data monthly, but unfortunately the aggregation date is the end of the month, while I would like to have the start of the month. Playing with none of the parameters of `TimeGrouper` has resolved this issue.

Output:

```
2003-01-31   29853   2071
2003-02-28   26668   2651
2003-03-31   37380   2324
2003-04-30   25344   1448
```

Expected output:

```
2003-01-01   29853   2071
2003-02-01   26668   2651
2003-03-01   37380   2324
2003-04-01   25344   1448
```

Here's the output using `label='left'`:

```
df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("M", label='left'), 'status']).sum()

                        TUFNWGTP  TELFS  t070101  t070102  t070103  t070104  \
TUDIARYDATE status                                                            
2002-12-31  emp     4.514715e+09   1244     8462      506     1265    19391   
            unemp   3.857707e+08    322      687       45      162     1147   
2003-01-31  emp     3.677095e+09   1015     7915      561     1300    16599   
            unemp   4.522924e+08    403     1073       34       42     1474
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use MS (Month-Start):

```
df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("MS", label='left'), 'status']).sum()
```

*see the [offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) in the docs.*